# Supremum of a sequence: $x_n = c_1 + c_2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form, divergent-series

I am dealing with a sequence

> $$
> x_n = c_1 + c_2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i
> $$

where $x_1 > 0$ and $c_1, c_2 > 0$ are constants. I am wondering whether one can find another series, call it $y_n$, that can be explicitly expressed in terms of $n$ and satisfies $x_n \leq y_n$ for each $n$.

I tried to rewrite the above recursive formula as
$$
(1 + c_2) x_n = c_1 + c_2 S_n
$$
where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, and obtained
$$
(c_2 n - 1) S_n = c_2 \sum_{i=1}^n i x_i - c_1 n
$$
I am struggling to find a way forward. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may observe that
$$
x_n = c_1 + c_2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \tag1
$$ gives
$$
x_{n+1} = c_1 + c_2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i. \tag2
$$ By making $(2)-(1)$, you just get
$$
x_{n+1}-x_n=c_2x_n \tag3
$$ or

> $$
> x_{n+1}=(1+c_2)\:x_n \tag4
> $$

which is easier to deal with.